# C# UWP BackgoundTask UserAway trigger on Desktop

Tags: c#, windows, triggers, win-universal-app, desktop

In my UWP Application, i have a BackgroundTask, triggered by the Presence and Absence of the User (UserPresent / UserAway). Now my Problem is, on the Desktop, the BackgroundTask is triggered several times, without the user logs out. If i let the Desktop stay for 15-20min, the Task is triggered, but why? The user is still present.
The second Problem i have, how can i let the UserAway trigger fire, if i shutdown my Desktop PC? When i log out the user on my Desktop, the trigger is fired without any issue, but if i shutdown, it isnt. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Does nobody know something to achieve this?